# MySQL backup dosen't work on cronjob

Tags: mysql, cron

I try to backup my DB everyday. When i run my script it works perfect. But when i put this into crontab the gz-archive is empty. It created an empty sql-file and after he compress it into gz-file.

Can anybody explain the difference between run directly and run through the cronjob??

```bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'`

mysqldump -u myUser -ptest*123 private_db | gzip > /mnt/backup#/MySQL/mysqlBackup_$DATE.sql.gz

if [ -f /mnt/backup#/MySQL/mysqlBackup_$DATE.sql.gz ]; then
        logger "Backup: MySQL private_db ...success"
else
        logger "Backup: MySQL private_db ...FAILED"
fi
```

Comment: what is the script name and what command are you using to create cron job? Are there any existing cron jobs in your environment?

Comment: This is an bash-script. And i put it into cron through "crontab -e". And yes there are few cronjobs before.

Cron execute the script, i see it in /var/log/messages. But the gz-file is empty.

Comment: I've tried your script. It works if I put it into crontab.

Comment: @quantummind do you unzip the file and there a really sql statements inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution. It was a problem depends on my OS. I use FreeBSD and the cronjob works as root. But cronjob root has different system environment as the user root. So i put some environment into my script.

```html
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'`

SHELL=/bin/csh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin

/usr/local/bin/mysqldump -u myUser -ptest*123 private_db | gzip > /mnt/backup#/MySQL/mysqlBackup_$DATE.sql.gz

if [ 1000 -gt $(wc -c </mnt/backup#/MySQL/mysqlBackup_$DATE.sql.gz) ];then
        logger "Backup: MySQL private_db ...FAILED (filesize to small )"
else
        if [ -f /mnt/backup#/MySQL/mysqlBackup_$DATE.sql.gz ]; then
                logger "Backup: MySQL private_db ...success"
        else
                logger "Backup: MySQL private_db ...FAILED"
        fi
fi
```